# Flutter app not keeping the settings made in the app after reopening the app

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have an app which has two tabs. One of the which is the "SAVED ITEMS" tab. When I save the items (from a different screen of ALL ITEMS LIST) it gets saved and on even switching the tabs works fine. But when I close the app and reopen it, the "SAVED ITEMS" list is empty and I've to select the items again. I've used the `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` but its not helping. Any idea on how to solve this folks?

My code:

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
super.build(context);
return MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  theme: ThemeData(
    primaryColor: Colors.blue,
    accentColor: Colors.white,
  ),
  home: DefaultTabController(
    length: 2,
    child: Scaffold(
      drawer: Drawer(),
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        title: Text('AIO'),
        bottom: TabBar(
          tabs: <Widget>[
            Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.search)),
            Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.favorite)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        children: <Widget>[
          gridView,
          SecondPage(),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}

@override
bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

SecondTab code:

```
Set<int> favorites = {};

class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_SecondPageState createState() => _SecondPageState();
}

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> 
with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
@override
bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
super.build(context);
return Stack(
  fit: StackFit.expand,
  children: <Widget>[
    _getFavoriteList(),
    Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(
            Icons.add,
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => EditFavorites(),
              ),
            ).then((updatedFavorites) {
              if (updatedFavorites != null)
                // setState(() {
                  favorites = updatedFavorites;
                // });
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    )
  ],
 );
 }
```

Comment: are you calling `updateKeepAlive` anywhere?

Comment: @AnirudhBagri no. where should I call it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences#-installing-tab-) dependency in `pubspec.yaml`

Update your `main()`

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  pref.getStringList("favorites")?.forEach((fav){
    favorites.add(int.tryParse(fav));
  });
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

then update your `SecondPage`

```
Set<int> favorites = {};

class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SecondPageState createState() => _SecondPageState();
}

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {
  Future<void> _upDateFavorites(Set<int> updatedFavorites) async {
    print("secong: u$updatedFavorites");
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    List<String> favoritesAsString =
    updatedFavorites.map((fav) => fav.toString()).toList(); //TODO: Change `favorites`  to `updatedFavorites`
    print(favoritesAsString);
    await pref.setStringList("favorites", favoritesAsString);  //TODO: await here to store it completely
    favorites = updatedFavorites;
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      fit: StackFit.expand,
      children: <Widget>[
        _getFavoriteList(),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              child: Icon(
                Icons.add,
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => EditFavorites(),
                  ),
                ).then((updatedFavorites) async {
                  if (updatedFavorites != null)
                    // setState(() {
                    _upDateFavorites(updatedFavorites);
                  // });
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _getFavoriteList() {
    if (favorites?.isNotEmpty == true)
      return _FavoriteList();
    else
      return _EmptyFavoriteList();
  }
}
```

Don't forget to `import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';` where you use `SharedPreferences`

Avoid storing widget in a vaiable, if it needs to be rebuild.

So delete `var favGridView = GridView.builder( ....`

```
class _FavoriteList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.builder(
      itemCount: favorites.length,
      gridDelegate:
          SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 3),
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        print("kkkkkkkkkkk: ${favorites.elementAt(index)}");
        return InkWell(
          child: Card(
            elevation: 10,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: Container(
                    child: Image.asset(
                        'lib/images/${images[favorites.elementAt(index)]}'), //TODO: Change this
                    // child: SizedBox(child: Text('yashjha'),),
                    // decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    //   image: DecorationImage(
                    //     image: AssetImage('lib/images/${images[index]}'),
                    //     fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                    //     alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                    //   ),
                    // ),
                  ),
                ),
                Text(nameOfSite[favorites.elementAt(index)]), //TODO: Change This
              ],
            ),
          ),
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Text("dsadsa")),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I also recommend using `actions` instead of `FloatingButton` in `_EditFavoritesState`. Because the floating button hides last item. which makes it unable to add to favorites

Comment: sorry to bother you but its not working. I've done exactly what you did but its not saving the preference I make. And when I reopen the app it starts from the beginning!??

Comment: @YashJha Can you push your latest code on [github](https://github.com/theyashjha/aioapp?files=1) like the other day?. Can I have a look.

Comment: @YashJha I made a small mistake in `_upDateFavorites` function. I updated the code. Pls check it again. Also read added `TODO:..`

Comment: wow. its finally working...that's just another level of problem solving. I'll again study the code againthanks for your help. This will be of immense help to beginners like me! Thank you once again!

Comment: sorry to bother you again but some error has occured. I'm adding items randomly but the items are storing as index wise (in which the list is arranged). I mean whether I click randomly five items, it'll store the five items from beginning. I checked the code but I'm just beginner so couldn't find the error!

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/theyashjha/aioapp/blob/master/secondtab.dart) is the code!

Comment: @YashJha I am unable to find `FavGridView` class. where can I find it?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/theyashjha/aioapp/blob/master/lists.dart) you go! I've updated it.

Comment: @YashJha I made a pull request. pls check it

Comment: now its working perfectly! thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

`AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` is used to retain the data when the app is running and you need to retain data while switching between tabs, pages etc.

 I would suggest you use `SharedPreferences` to easily save data to your memory that can be retrieved when the app is started again.

 `SharedPreferences`: https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences